# Why am i getting the error of "List Index out of range"

Tags: python, list

Im trying to make a connect four game. My 2d list prints only one 0. I've looked through many sources[image]

Im attempting to print my 2d list "Board"

Comment: Welcome to SO. [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: `print(board[rows][cols])` ?

Comment: Trying that it runs the error "Name "rows" is not the defined"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

line 16:

```py
print([rows][cols], end=' ')
```

should be

```py
print(board[rows][cols], end=' ')
```